# Can I change the kernel used in Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker, kernel

I want to run a set of docker containers but with a custom kernel.

Since Docker for Windows is already using Hyper-V, could it be possible to change which image is running?

Answer (score 2):

Docker uses its own patched Kernel (along with a specialized Linux distro) called [linuxkit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit) in Docker Desktop. It is mentioned in https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/for-desktop-kernel.

I am able to find `kernel`, `initrd.img` and `cmdline` in a folder called `linuxkit` inside the application folder of my Docker for Mac installation.

I assume that you will find a similar folder inside the Windows installation.

Simply build your own Kernel with the instructions/patches of `linuxkit` and replace those files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Windows. But the Kernel that your VM is running is the Kernel that is used for all your Docker containers. So, my naive guess would be, changing the VM's Kernel would work.

I'm assuming Hyper-V is the hypervisor. That would create a VM (running a Linux Kernel) on top of which the Docker containers are running.

Comment: My question is how to change the vm kernel for the vm Docker is creating

Comment: Well, I was trying to give you an high-level understanding of what's going on and what is necessary. As I mentioned, I'm not familiar with Windows, hence can't tell you about the nitty-gritty details.

But as now you know the high-level details, some searching around the Internet should help I suppose? Something along the lines of "Docker Windows change default Kernel" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would also love to get answer for this question...

I would like to use "Docker Desktop for Windows" and it uses Linux Kernel 4.9.184 but I would like to use Kernel Version 3.10.0-1062. I want to use older Kernel because it is the Kernel for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.

Link for Docker Desktop Community Linux Kernel version
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/

Link for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Kernel Version
https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL7